# Oracle Semantic Web-SEM_RELATED operator does not produce desired results

Tags: oracle, semantic-web, ontology

I am trying the same scenario which Oracle Semantics Web documentation has listed for querying Cancer Ontology.
Below are the steps which I have followed.

1). Created a tablespace.

```
CREATE TABLESPACE rdf_tblspace
DATAFILE 'C:\app\swagh\oradata\orcl\rdf_tblspace.dat' SIZE 1024M REUSE;
```

2). Created a semantic data network.

```
EXECUTE SEM_APIS.CREATE_SEM_NETWORK('rdf_tblspace');
```

3). Created a application table for storing triples.

```
CREATE TABLE articles_rdf_data (id NUMBER, triple SDO_RDF_TRIPLE_S);
```

4). Creted a semantic model.

```
EXECUTE SEM_APIS.CREATE_SEM_MODEL('articles', 'articles_rdf_data', 'triple');
```

5). Inserted Cancer Ontology data into semantic model.

```
INSERT INTO articles_rdf_data VALUES (1,
SDO_RDF_TRIPLE_S ('articles','Immunodeficiency-Syndrome',
    'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf',
    'Immune_System_Disorder'));

INSERT INTO articles_rdf_data VALUES (2,
  SDO_RDF_TRIPLE_S ('articles','T_Cell_Immunodeficiency',
    'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf',
    'Immunodeficiency-Syndrome')); 

INSERT INTO articles_rdf_data VALUES (3,
  SDO_RDF_TRIPLE_S ('articles','AIDS',
    'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf',
    'T_Cell_Immunodeficiency'));
```

6). Created a patient table and inserted a record with following values in it.

```
CREATE TABLE patients (id INT, diagnosis VARCHAR2(100));
INSERT INTO patients VALUES (1,'AIDS');
```

7). Executed a ontology based semantic query.

```
SELECT diagnosis FROM patients 
WHERE SEM_RELATED (diagnosis, 
'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf',
'http://www.example.org/medical_terms/Immune_System_Disorder', 
sem_models('articles'), null) = 1;
```

This query should return `AIDS` as diagnosis value, as `AIDS` is subclass of `T_Cell_Immunodeficiency` which in turn subclass of `Immunodeficiency-Syndrome` and `Immune_System_Disorder` classes, whereas it does not return anything.
Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this Oracle functionality but I can see the namespace of your classes only in your query. Can you double check that the stored namespace matches the query?

Comment: Also, probably, you have to enable [inferencing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28397/owl_concepts.htm#RDFRM618). Try to write `sem_rulebases('owlprime')` instead of `null` in 7.

Comment: Hi Stanislav,
Thanks for your reply.
If I try to add inferencing by adding sem_rulebases('owlprime') instead of null, it gives me a error message saying that "ORA-55456: no valid rules index for this model-rulebase combination".
However, Oracle documentation has provided a script to create an index which is as follows.

Comment: CREATE INDEX diagnosis_sem_idx
  ON patients (diagnosis) 
  INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SEM_INDEXTYPE('ONTOLOGY_MODEL(medical_ontology), 
    RULEBASE(OWLPrime)');
 
But, unfortunately this script doesn't work and has syntax error.
Moreover, I resolved the above issue by creating an entailment, but still the query does not return anything.

Comment: Well, try to make a query that does not rely on transitivity of `subclassOf`. Is this query successfull?